# How to fetch values from the below array

Tags: php, arrays

need help to get values from the below array , i'm getting the below array in `print_r($_REQUEST)`.

```
Array ( 
    [DATA] => RespCode=0&Message=Transaction+Successful&TxnID=547635502&ePGTxnID=201704043545620&AuthIdCode=087470&RRN=000064005897&Amount=2&CVRespCode=Y&Reserve3=null&MID=96065339&isCitrusNBFlag=false 
    [MID] => 96065339 
    [EncryptedData] => 58E0AF8EA8E2A31F3117AEFBD198CAE863E4B754 
    [roundcube_cookies] => enabled 
    [PHPSESSID] => f7ok4hhl8sdaig86k04tsr4ss3 
    [__zlcmid] => eXg8skYnKUkdck 
)
```

i want values for RespCode and CVRespCode.

I tried every possible way i know to make it work but unable to do so .
I know is simple thing , but sorry unable to make it work .

Thanks for your help in advance .

Comment: And whats an example of "every possible way you know"? Show some code, please :-)

Comment: is this a var_dump of the array?

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST)

Comment: i'm getting this array on response page of a payment gateway and i want to update database on the basis of the response returned .

Answer (score 4):

You need [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for this,

```
parse_str($array['DATA'], $output);
echo $output['RespCode'];
echo $output['CVRespCode'];
```

Here is [Demo](https://eval.in/767465)

**Here is test results from CLI**

```
[akshay@db2 tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php

$array=array(
    "DATA"=>"RespCode=0&Message=Transaction+Successful&TxnID=547635502&ePGTxnID=201704043545620&AuthIdCode=087470&RRN=000064005897&Amount=2&CVRespCode=Y&Reserve3=null&MID=96065339&isCitrusNBFlag=false"
);

parse_str($array["DATA"], $output);
echo "Resp Code: ". $output['RespCode'].PHP_EOL;
echo "CV Resp Code: ". $output['CVRespCode'].PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

print_r($output);
?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@db2 tmp]$ php test.php
Resp Code: 0
CV Resp Code: Y

Array
(
    [RespCode] => 0
    [Message] => Transaction Successful
    [TxnID] => 547635502
    [ePGTxnID] => 201704043545620
    [AuthIdCode] => 087470
    [RRN] => 000064005897
    [Amount] => 2
    [CVRespCode] => Y
    [Reserve3] => null
    [MID] => 96065339
    [isCitrusNBFlag] => false
)
```

Comment: i'm getting this array on response page of a payment gateway and i want to update database on the basis of the response returned .  the array i provided is what i'm getting in "print_r($_REQUEST)" on the response page .

Comment: @phpdev then do `parse_str($_REQUEST["DATA"], $output);` (or if you know it's a `$_GET` or `$_POST` change it accordingly.

Comment: @phpdev you would need to just get DATA from $_REQUEST array by using $_REQUEST['DATA'] and use the logic provided by Akshay

Answer (score 0):

you could expode the string using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and save that in a `var` like so:

`$explodedArray = explode( '&', $yourArray['DATA']);`

then you can use it like this: `$explodedArray[0]` where 0 is in this case your RespCode

If the values could be in different positions you could expode the string and then loop through until you find the value you need.

```
$explodedArray = explode( '&', $yourArray['DATA']);

foreach($explodedArray as $val) {
    if($val == "RespCode") {
        //do something with respcode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_str($_REQUEST["DATA"], $output);
            $resp=$output['RespCode'];
            $cod=$output['CVRespCode'];
```

did the needed work , i'm not sure why some are so fast in giving minus feedback then helping out . Thanks @akshay @Samarth